# Если не работает RigidBody.velocity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Скрипт прикреплён к `gun`, `bullet` имеет компоненты RB2D, CapsuleCollider2D. Происходит создание объекта `bullet`, но объект не двигается, в остальном код работает. В чём может быть проблема ? Значения `bulletSpeed = 20`, а вот `instantiatedBullet.velocity = (0.0, 0.0)`

```
 public Transform target;
public float offsetGun;
public GameObject gun;
private Vector3 targetPos;
private Vector3 thisPos;
private float angle;
private float nextFire = 0.0f;
public float fireRate = 1.0f;
public Rigidbody2D bullet;
public float bulletSpeed = 20.0f;

public void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
}
public void Update()
{
    targetPos = target.position;
    thisPos = gun.transform.position;
    targetPos.x = targetPos.x - thisPos.x;
    targetPos.y = targetPos.y - thisPos.y;
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetPos.y, targetPos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle + offsetGun));

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    attack();
}

void attack()
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);
    if (dist <= 50)
    {
        if (Time.time > nextFire)
        {
            //Debug.Log(bullet);
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Rigidbody2D instantiatedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
            instantiatedBullet.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А `transform.forward`?

Comment: @user7860670 реализовано `instantiatedBullet.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;`

Comment: `Rigidbody2D instantiatedBullet = Instantiate(...) as Rigidbody2D;` а так вообще допустимо? Попробуй `GameObject NewBullet = Instantiate(...); Rigidbody2D BulletRB = NewBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D >();`

Comment: @Yaroslav `GameObject` не удастся преобразовать в `Rigidbody2D`, так как в `Instantiate(bullet, gun.transform.position, gun.transform.rotation)` объект `bullet` - `Rigidbody2D`. Даже если `bullet` будет объявлен как `GameObject bullet`, всё равно будет тот же эффект, только что проверил.

Comment: Преобразовать `GameObject` в `Rigidbody2D`? Что? `Rigidbody2D` вообще не объект, а компонент объекта.

Comment: @Yaroslav в Visual Studio написано **неудаётся преобразовать GameObject в Rigidbody2D**

Answer (score -3):

Скрипт для игрока.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Bullet;
    public Transform SpawnPoint;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Instantiate(Bullet, SpawnPoint.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Скрипт для пули

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed;
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        // Или любой другой способ перемещения
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага... и collision event не произойдёт...